# how to do slam with a custom robot in Gazebo?

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, laser, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to build a map using SLAM(gmapping) and my own (virtual) robot which is equipped with a hokuyo LRF under Gazebo, i have looked around but could not find a tutorial on how to do this.
for example

http://wiki.ros.org/robotino_navigation/Tutorials/Mapping%20with%20Robotino
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM

these tutorials don't explain how to do it with a customized robot.

my question is how do i obtain the laser scan data and pass it to the corresponding listener? I've noticed in some tutorials it is published by a topic named /base_scan,which does not appear when i load the model into the Gazebo environment.

Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226540/how-to-do-slam-with-a-custom-robot-in-gazebo?/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2018-01-31**:
Hello! I have the same problem a long time now. DId you find any solution to the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

buy the Book
Programming Robots with ROS: A Practical Introduction to the Robot Operating System
It hast an step by step tutorial and it easy to read.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0